# how good if you have more than one controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assuming I have 10 angularjs controllers on my HTML line,

Example my html file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="firstController">
  bla bla bla
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="secondController">
  bla bla bla
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="thirdController">
  bla bla bla
 </div>
 <div ng-controller="fourthController">
  bla bla bla
 </div>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <div ng-controller="tenthController">
  bla bla bla
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with a situation like the one above what should I be like? for all controllers it should be made into one .js file or each controller one for .js file and how do you include these controllers for good performance?

1.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="firstController.js"></script>
 <script src="secondController.js"></script>
 <script src="thirdController.js"></script>
 <script src="fourthController.js"></script>
 .
 .
 .
 <script src="tenthController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

or

2.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="allControllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

need help master